# WCF Base address overridden by App.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Today I started delving into WCF. I took to the tutorial at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx

I walked through this tutorial up until where you host the service host. The tutorial segment [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx) told me start up the service and then navigate to the uri specified in code. When I did that my connection was refused. After a short while of messing around, I found that the base address was specified in the app.config as something else entirely. Navigating to that URI followed by the endpoint name took me where I wanted to go. I don't know how that address was generated, and don't really care all that much. What I'm more interested in is what purpose setting the base URI on the services plays when it seemingly has no effect whatsoever, and the actual base URI that is used comes from the app.config. It's required by the constructor of the [ServiceHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost(v=vs.110).aspx) type... so you would think its important. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully at the two constructors of `ServiceHost` that are expecting Uris, the Uri parameter is prefixed with `params`.

In C#, it means  you can pass as many Uris as you want, including zero.

Passing no Uri is interesting if you want to use the  of the app.config.

If you got no configuration, you pass a type or an object and some Uris.
Then WCF creates  a service that is expose all the interfaces of the service on all the Uris.

For instance if you ve got two interfaces in you service and you call :

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService), 
                       "net.tcp://localhost:7000/service1", 
                       "net.pipe://localhost:8000/service1", 
                       "http://localhost:9000/service1");
```

You 'll get 2x3 exposed endpoints

Most of the time `ServiceHost` are built without providing addresses.

Config is made in XML.

Regards

Comment: I was wondering if this was in cases where no app.config is present. Seems like thats what you mean.

Comment: Actually You Can make all the configuration from pure .net code with no Xml at all. You can also mix the approaches for having some base config plus some dynamic configuration